# Google Earth app KMZ overlay hidden by 3D tees and buildings

Tags: google-earth, overlay, kmz

I've got a KMZ layer with an overlay layer in the `<groundoverlay>` tag.
I've got 3d buildings and trees in the overlay area, and they hide the overlay.

In Google Earth app it is not possible to disable 3d buildings.
Do you know if there is a tip to have the overlay always visible and attached to the ground in Google Earth app for smartphones and tablets?

Comment: Looks like you cannot but another idea is to force the smartphone/tablet to use the desktop/web version rather than the installed app version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334481/how-to-force-desktop-view-on-mobile-devices-bootstrap

Comment: @Mapperz I've got the same problem opening the KMZ on earth.google.com. I cannot share the link because the KMZ loaded in browser is not saved.

Answer (score 0):

For those finding this same issue 5+ years later, here's the solution!
Go to Tools/3D View and de-select the option under Terrain called "Use 3D Imagery"